# FCM DeliveryReceipts

Tags: java, android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can see in FCM Documentation that FCM sends DeliveryReports to FireBase console alone and the support for XMPP upstream messaging has been deprecated

Ref:
1.https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery

2.https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream

3.https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#december_17_2019

Is there any Approach where the Backend AppServer receives the Delivery Information about the Notification sent to the Android/IOS Device.Which is present Out of Box in FCM.

Is there a webHook Support where the updates are relayed back to the AppServer